# Transmission on FreeNAS umask / owner of files

Tags: freebsd, bittorrent, nas, transmission, umask

going slightly crazy with Transmission installed on FreeNas 8.3.1 (not in a jail)

Everything is fine except the ownership / permissions of the downloaded files, they are all owned by root and have mask: rwxr-sr-x

I have tried changing 'umask' in settings.json from 18 to 0 (read it somewhere) but that doesn't help, it appears to be ignored; 
what I want is for ANY user to be able to delete these files (rw.rw.rw.), or at a minimum the group, not just the owner; I don't know what I should change umask to for this to work. Probably really easy if you understand umask...

alternatively, how do I change the settings so the owner is another user, not root; i start the transmission on startup as a service /daemon, I tried changing the start up script to add daemon-user, but it seems ignored as well, files are still created by root.

any tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed transmission as a FreeNAS plugin, checkout that plugin's configuration options in the GUI as shown [here](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Plugins).

If you installed it manually, have a look at [this page](http://www.mysticg.com/2013/01/15/freenas-jail-with-transmission/). It shows you how to configure transmission from `/etc/rc.conf`. This certainly gives you the option to run transmission as an ordinary user instead of as root, which seems a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is to use the Plugin architecture. That being said you could create a cronjob to re-apply the wanted permissions on a given folder or series of files.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should check:

1. Did you stop the daemon before editing the settings.json file?

   ```
   service transmission stop
   ```
2. Does the user that runs transmission-daemon have ownership of the download-dir specified in your settings.json?

Try

```
    "umask": 2,
```

which should make your files owner and group writeable.